# Vue.js - Using parent data in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

How I can get access to parent's data variable (limitByNumber) in my child component Post?

I tried to use prop but it doesn't work.

**Parent:**

```
import Post from './components/Post.vue';

new Vue ({
    el: 'body',

    components: { Post },

    data: {
        limitByNumber: 4
    }
});
```

**Component Post:**

```
<template>
    <div class="Post" v-for="post in list | limitBy limitByNumber">
    <!-- Blog Post -->
    ....
    </div>
</template>

<!-- script -->    
<script>
export default {
    props: ['list', 'limitByNumber'],
    
    created() {
        this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can use Dependency-Injection, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### Option 1

Use `this.$parent.limitByNumber` from child component. So your Component template would be like this

```
<template>
    <div class="Post" v-for="post in list | limitBy this.$parent.limitByNumber" />                
</template>
```

### Option 2

If you want to use props, you can also achieve what you want. Like this.

**Parent**

```
<template>
    <post :limit="limitByNumber" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            limitByNumber: 4
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Child Pots**

```
<template>
    <div class="Post" v-for="post in list | limitBy limit">
        <!-- Blog Post -->
        ....
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['list', 'limit'],

    created() {
        this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you don't need the `this.` before `$parent`.

Comment: Is there a way to do something like `$(this).closest('#parent_element_id')` does in jQuery? Although, `this.$parent` is pretty good, I've ended up with things like: `this.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.xxxx` in one of my components… Need a quick way to refactor this weirdness =)

Comment: @pilat Have you ever found a solution ?

Comment: or for you, @pilat?

Comment: @pilat Things that helped me for that situation:
- Generally use `$emit()` to transfer changes to the parent (and their parents, and their parents...).
- The DOM can be interacted with using `ref` attributes (google vue ref attribute). This is mostly for a component interacting with its DOM, usually not with its parents.
- If you really need to change something across the DOM hierarchy, consider using Vue Portal: https://linusborg.github.io/portal-vue/

Comment: in case the `$parent.$parent.$parent` you are trying to access is the root component you can access it directly with `$root` @pilat, I know it's a year old comment but maybe it helps someone else.

Comment: I realise this is old but using `this.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.xxxx` is not the right approach as you're coupling the child component to the parent (and their parents). This is why you use props. Say you wanted to move one of those nested child components somewhere else? Well, you can't, because they rely on that specific parent hierarchical structure being in place.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to access some specific parent, you can name all components like this:

```
export default {
    name: 'LayoutDefault'
```

And then add some function (maybe like vue.prototype or Mixin if you need it in all your components). Something like this should do it:

```
getParent(name) {
    let p = this.$parent;
    while(typeof p !== 'undefined') {
        if (p.$options.name == name) {
            return p;
        } else {
            p = p.$parent;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and usage could be like this:

```
this.getParent('LayoutDefault').myVariableOrMethod
```

Comment: This is assuming that all your parent components up the tree have unique names (which it should have anyway) but that's a pretty cool option for what I need to do right now so thank you