# Why isn't the child component receiving data from the root?

Tags: vue.js

Really simple setup, but I am having issues when teaching myself. Main app.js initializes

```
var app = new Vue({
    mixins: [require('spark')],
    data: {
        treeData: data
    }
});
```

I have my home.js component here:

```
Vue.component('home', {
    props: ['user', 'treeData'],

    ready() {
        console.log(this.user);
        console.log(this.treeData);
    }
});
```

And while the data in the root is populated correctly for both `treeData` and `user`, the `<home>` component is not receiving the data. See my attached images of the root and home components pulled from the vue.js devtools in Chrome.

What am I missing?

[image: treeData is undefined]

Comment: How are you passing data to the `Home` component?

Comment: Ugh. That was my mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. I did not have it as part of the template definition. Now it works like this: `<home :user="user" :tree-data="treeData" inline-template>`. I had it in my head that the data was passed just by making the props available. Are there multiple ways to pass data to a child component?

Comment: Check my answer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722170/vue-js-using-parent-data-in-component). If you want to access the data from the parent, there is the  `this.$children` array, but be carefull, because you have access to all child components, including different components or multiple instances of the same component

Comment: Good to know, although the docs mention specifically to not use this approach and access data only within the components scope. If that component needs the data, make it available. Is the way I showed in the above comment the only way to pass data to a child component outside of pushing it via events?

Comment: Yes, you normally only pass data to components via props or events.