# Vue2.0 unaccessible variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've am new at Vue and i've got a problem with unaccessible. I've got two files.

1st is App.vue where is defined `<router-view>`

```
<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data(){
    return{
      info: false,
    }
  },
  beforeMount(){
        example...
        this.info= true
        this.$router.push('/main'); //where in router-view visible is component Main.vue

      }
  }

</script>
```

2nd is component Main.vue which is clear:

```
<script>
export default{
    name: 'main',
    data(){
        return{

        }
    },
    beforeMount(){
        //what i want to do:
        console.log(App.data().info) //here should be visible true in console log
    } 
}
```

i would like to have accessible in 2nd file the property from file number one. How to do it properly? Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the relationship between app and main?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js - Using parent data in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722170/vue-js-using-parent-data-in-component)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js - Using parent data in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722170/vue-js-using-parent-data-in-component)

Comment: this.$parent.info seems to work fine but, when i manually refload the window it's again false.  why? Does after page reload App's beforeMount() is not working?

Comment: How to explain hmm... i would like to have a global function that in every refresh/reload sets info = true and that value is accessible in every subsite /component. i thought that beforeMount() from Vue.app is executed every reload/refresh because there is defined <router-view>. am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options that i can think of :

1. Passing Props to Route Components

Source : [link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html)

In your router :

```
import main from './main.vue'

    const router = new VueRouter({
      routes: [
        { path: '/main/:id', component: main }
      ]
    })
```

In your Main.vue

> Access to the variable : this.$route.params.id

---

2. Save the data in state manager and get access to him through the state in another component [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

Every component instance has its own isolated scope. As stated here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

> you cannot (and should not) directly reference parent data in a child component’s template. Data can be passed down to child components using props.